# Azure DevOps: How to automatically re-deploy a stage if it fails on the first attempt

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Instead of manually redeploying a stage, I want to achieve an automatic way to redeploy(can be done manually).
My stage include some disk operations, which sometime fails on the first attempt but usually succeeds on the second attempt.

I am currently re-running the task group into another job in the same stage.
The second job basically executes only if the first one fails.
But this marks the stage as failed as out of two jobs, first one has failed.
But in my case both the jobs are same. Can't find a way to redeploy the same stage.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are basically keep doing what you have or you can replace the steps that fail with custom PowerShell/Bash script that knows how to retry.

Edit: You could improve your existing solution little bit by putting your second attempt in the same job as your first attempt. That way you wouldn't get a failed stage. You can put conditions on steps and not just jobs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml